# Match recursive pattern consisting of multiple relations in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I got a Database model as depicted in picture(1) where each Person has an age property and I want to query all children of second order which are the son of a daughter (age > 50) starting at a given node. For the given Database scheme my expected result starting at Bob would be [Tim, Sam].

[image]

I already tried the '*' operator for querying relationships of variable lengths but couldn't get it to work so far. I tried

```
START bob=node(0) MATCH (bob)-[:daughter*]->(p:Person)-[:son*]->(s)
WHERE p.age > 50 RETURN bob, sbob, s
```

which returns only Bob and Tim, as well as

```
MATCH (:Person)-[:daughter*]->(p:Person)-[:son*]->(s) 
WHERE p.age > 50 RETURN collect(s)
```

which gives me [Tim, Bob, Tom, Sam].

Is there any way to get my expected result without changing the database structure?

*Update*
As an extra requirement all daugthers along a path must be older than 50, i.e. if Tina is 48 and Carmen is 52 (while practically impossible) an empty collection is returned (the ages of the sons don't matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//
// Find daughters with age > 50
MATCH (bob:Person {name:'Bob'}), path = (bob)-[:son|daughter*]->(d:Person)
  WHERE type( last(relationships(path)) ) = 'daughter' and d.age>50
//
// Check if all daughters at path over age 50
WITH d, nodes(path) as nodes, relationships(path) as rels,
     range( 0, length(path)-1 ) as index
  WHERE none( i in index 
                WHERE type( rels[i] ) = 'daughter' AND 
                      nodes[i+1]['age'] <= 50
        )    
//
// Find sons of daughter
MATCH (d)-[:son]->(s:Person)
RETURN collect(s)
```

Comment: This solves my question when assuming that children are younger than their parents. While practically impossible I want to omit this assumption in my question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Executing your query I get a type mismatch when accessing the age property using neo4j 2.2.3. I was able to work around this by using `extract` to get a collection with the ages of all nodes in the path. Thank you very much for your help